# Operaciones con ficheros (copiar, borrar) desde tarea cron no funcionan

Tags: archivo, raspberry-pi, cron, raspbian

Tengo una raspberry modelo 3A donde estoy recogiendo datos de varios sensores. Los datos los proceso con un script en python y los almaceno en un fichero datos.csv.

Quiero hacer una copia de seguridad del fichero datos.csv de forma periódica, cada 15 días. Para ello he preparado un script en php que hace lo siguiente, paso a paso:

- Comprime el fichero datos.csv mediante shellexec y 7z a un fichero ./ruta_copia_seg/datos_202403_001.7z. 202403 es el año y el mes y 001 es la primera copia, 002 será la segunda.
- Comprueba que la copia comprimida es correcta con 7z t ./ruta_copia_seg/datos_202403_001.7z. Para ello recojo la salida y busco la cadena "Everithing is Ok".
- Si todo va bien, borra el fichero datos.csv y copia una plantilla ./res/datos-vacio.csv a un nuevo fichero datos.csv en blanco para empezar a recoger datos.

Todo esto se hace de forma correcta si ejecuto el fichero php desde la terminal, pero, aquí está el problema, si lo hago desde una tarea cron, no funciona nada.

Tarea cron:
55 23 15,L * * sudo php /home/angel/run/opficheros.php >> /home/angel/run/opficheros.log 2 >> /home/angel/run/fallos.log

En la variable var/log/syslog obtengo el error:
Mar 16 15:51:01 raspberrypi CRON[4619]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)

Y el fichero fallos.log:
./ruta_copia_seg/datos_202403_002.7z comprimido correcto
2024-03-16 15:51:01 Hubo un error al copiar la plantilla.

Leyendo en foros, he visto que "No MTA..." es un fallo que se da cuando quieres enviar ficheros por email y se puede corregir instalando postfix, pero leo que esto instala un servidor SMTP. ¿Necesito un servidor SMTP para trabajar con ficheros en local desde una tarea cron?

Comment: Un MTA (como Postfix) es necesario para que el sistema pueda enviar notificaciones por email, en este caso es CRON que después de que la tarea falle intenta notificar al administrador por email de ello, pero no es necesario para la tarea ni es la causa de que esté fallando.

Comment: Por cierto, parece que escalas privilegios con sudo al ejecutar tu script, si requiere ingresar contraseña (a no ser que lo tengas configurado para que no en sudoers, o la proporciones como texto plano en la crontab, pésima idea por cierto) CRON no te va a poder pedir que la ingreses... Si necesitas escalar privilegios para el script puedes usar la crontab de root (`sudo crontab -e`) de forma que no necesite de sudo para su ejecución. La tarea puede estar fallando  precisamente la falta de permisos o por otras razones relacionadas con CRON como la falta de variables de entorno.

Comment: Gracias FJSevilla por tus comentarios. Efectivamente, la causa de que falle es otra. Lo explico a continuación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues parece que lo he resuelto:
Se trata de dos cosas que hay que tener siempre presente en las tareas que se lanzan con CRON: Los permisos de los archivos donde quieres escribir y las rutas de esos archivos. El problema lo he solucionado poniendo rutas absolutas al fichero datos.csv. Antes ponía "./datos_20240319.csv" y hay que poner "/home/angel/run/datosseg/datos_20240319.csv"

Comment: En el fondo el problema parece el mismo que el de: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/616798/15089. Efectivamente CRON por defecto ejecuta (CWD) desde el HOME del usuario propietario de la crontab, por lo que o bien usas una ruta absoluta harcodeada o una relativa pero teniendo el cuenta esto, o directamente cambias el CWD.