# problemas para ejecutar tarea en crontab con python

Tags: python-3.x, linux, crontab, red-hat

hola buenas tardes a todos y primero gracias por detenerse a leer mi consulta

Tengo un linux redhat8, donde tengo un script en python3 y cuando lo ejecuto desde consola me crear y un archivo con la cadena de texto que le indico hasta ahi todo bien.

```py
x =   {
  "name": "John",
  "age": 30,
  "city": "New York"
}

with open("archivo.txt","w") as file:
        for y in x:
                print(y)
                file.write(str(y))
file.close()
```

Ahora quiero hacer que esta creación sea dinamica y programada.
Utilizo crontad y este me lee el script de python pero no me crea el archivo.

Estuve revisando que debo darle permisos y fue lo que hice permisos de escritura y ejecución.

```
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 systemadm systemadm 159 Mar 21 16:25 test.py
```

la configuración de crontad es la siguiente

```
* * * * * python3 /home/systemadm/micarpeta/test.py
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Vaya a saber donde está ejecutando el script. Deberías crear un batch que se cambie al directorio correcto y luego ejecute el script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### ¿Dónde crea ese script el archivo?

La ruta que le especificas a `open` es una ruta relativa, `"archivo.txt"` o lo que es lo mismo `"./archivo.txt"`. El error que seguramente estás cometiendo es asumir que la ruta se resuelve en base a la localización del propio script de Python (*test.py*), pero la ruta es relativa **[al directorio de trabajo actual (CWD)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directorio_de_trabajo)** del intérprete.

Si llamas a tu script desde la terminal así:

```
$ cd /home/systemadm/micarpeta
$ python test.py
```

dado que estas en la misma ruta donde está el script y ejecutas el interprete desde esa ruta, el directorio de trabajo será el mismo del script y el archivo se creará en ese mismo directorio.

Si en cambio haces:

```
$ cd /home/systemadm
$ python /micarpeta/test.py
```

ahora el directorio de trabajo es `/home/systemadm` y es aquí donde el archivo se creará.

### ¿Y cuál es el CWD cuando cron ejecuta mi script?

El demonio cron establece varias variables de entorno, entre ellas está `HOME`, la cual se establece en base a la linea correspondiente en `/etc/passwd` del usuario de esa crontab.

Así que seguramente el archivo creado por tu script esté en  `/home/systemadm`...

### ¿Cómo lo soluciono?

Tienes varias posibilidades, entre ellas:

- Sobrescribir la variable `HOME` en la crontab, por ejemplo (`/etc/cron.d/test`):

  ```
  SHELL=/bin/sh
  HOME=/home/systemadm/micarpeta
  PATH=/home/systemadm/micarpeta:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

  * * * * * systemadm python3 test.py
  ```
- Cambiar el directorio de trabajo con `cd` antes de ejecutar el script:

  ```
    * * * * * cd /home/systemadm/micarpeta/ && python3 test.py
  ```
- Cambiar el directorio de trabajo desde el propio script:

  ```
  import os

  os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))

  x = {
      "name": "John",
      "age": 30,
      "city": "New York"
  }

  with open("archivo.txt", "w", encoding="UTF-8") as file:
      for y in x:
          print(y)
          file.write(str(y))
  ```
- Especificar la ruta absoluta a `open`, bien hardcodeada o mediante `__file__` de nuevo:

  ```
  from pathlib import Path

  x = {
      "name": "John",
      "age": 30,
      "city": "New York"
  }

  ruta = Path(__file__).parent.joinpath("archivo.txt")
  with open(ruta, "w", encoding="UTF-8") as file:
      for y in x:
          print(y)
          file.write(str(y))
  ```

---

**Nota 1**: El atributo [`__file__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) contiene la ruta desde la cual el módulo ha sido cargado. A partir de Python 3.9 se garantiza que esta ruta es absoluta.

**Nota 2**: Dos apuntes anecdóticos sobre el código en si, no necesitas llamar a `close` explícitamente si estas usando el gestor de contexto (cláusula `with`), el archivo se cerrará cuando termine la ejecución del bloque. Por otro lado, es buena práctica especificar siempre la codificación del archivo a usar de forma explícita, de lo contrario será dependiente de la plataforma.

Answer (score 1):

Trata de no usar rutas relativas. En lugar de eso, escribe la ruta completa en tu programa:

```py
with open("/ruta/completa/a/archivo.txt","w") as file:
    for y in x:
        print(y)
        file.write(str(y))
```